# Outlook 2013 - get item from public calendar

Tags: outlook

how get items from public calendar? I tried the following, but it appears to me the error object not found

```
var ol = new ActiveXObject("outlook.application");
var calendar = ol.getnamespace("mapi").folders("public folder – name").Folders("All Public Folders").Folders("Company").Folders("Room").items
```

Thank you

Comment: Split that line into multiple lines and retrieve one folder at a time. Which one fails?

Comment: var calendar = ol.getnamespace("mapi").folders("public folder – name").items return object not found